# Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to migrate my apps from google cloud messaging (GCM) to firebase cloud messaging (FCM). The doc says that we need to put this function

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) { 
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox)
}
```

But I get unresolved identifier on `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox` even I already import `Firebase`, `FirebaseInstanceID`, `FirebaseMessaging`. Do you know why?
I appreciate any kind of clue from u guys. Thanks!

Comment: yes, I did. What should I import on my `BridgingHeader` file? I've tried to import `Google/CloudMessaging.h` and `Firebase/Messaging` but not found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Swift, you have to use 
FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox instead of FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox.

It works for me.